# MongoDB Grails GORM unexpected behavior with hasMany / belongsTo

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Context: I'm using the mongodb plugin, although this may have nothing to do with that.

Let's say I have two domain classes, Foo and Bar, where Foo hasMany Bar and Bar belongsTo Foo:

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bar:Bar]
}

class Bar {
    static belongsTo = [foo:Foo]
}
```

I would expect that what would be stored would be a collection (or table) for Foo, an collection for Bar, and a FooBar collection that handles the mappings. Instead I am getting a Foo collection and a Bar collection, where Bar has a "foo" key. It seems like what is happening would be the expected result of only adding the belongsTo but omitting the hasMany...

A) Are my expectations simply incorrect and what is happening is the expected result?
B) If not A, is there something special I need to do to make it match my expectations?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know mongodb is non relational database, that is why what is happening is correct, it doesn't create third table or collection for handling has many but as you are using mongodb plugin , you can query it like has many/belongsTo as you generally use with mysql. In your case db structure for foo would be:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1), "version" : 0  }
```

and for Bar would be:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1), "foo" : NumberLong(1), "version" : 0 }
```

And it will provide you, as it is  cascade delete from parent to child like in case of using mysql

Hope It Helps:)

Comment: So this is the expected result. Good to know!